# How to install C++ library to VS2012?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I am not familiar with the way to install the libraries. I've downloaded the library which I need and there are some *.h in the include folder and *.cpp in the src folder.But what makes me mad is that I don't know how to use them.Just put them into the include folder of VS2012? I know how to install Python' libraries but have no idea with C++'s.Should I install them or just copy them to the right folder? Please help me, thank you.

Comment: Can you be specific about which library in particular?

Comment: It pains me that even with all my experience in the language, I cannot answer this question in a very straightforward manner. There is not one single way to do this that works for all libraries. Usually, the correct answer is "follow the instructions given by the library's authors", and even that doesn't work all the time.

Comment: `C++` is completely different from `Python`. With Visual Studio you have to add this library to your project. You need its `dll` or `lib` file for compiled library, and if it is just source code you don't have to compile separatelly, you have to add it to your project. You have to be more specific in what library you try to install to get help. In `C++` there are not "universal" solution.

Comment: Usually you would put them in a directory somewhere and either add them to your project like you would files you created yourself, or make a new project that creates a static library or dll you link to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a static library
1) Go to Project Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories -> Place here the path of your library ( .lib ) file
2) Project Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies -> Place the name of your .lib file here.

If it's a dynamic link library
1) Go to Project Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories -> Place here the path of your library ( .lib ) file
2) Project Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies -> Place the name of your .lib file here.
3) Now when you run the exe make sure that your .dll file is in the current directory where you run the exe or make sure the path of the .dll is in the environment path.

Hope this helps in your case.